# Silverlight 5 SDK SLSvcUtil errors after install VS 2015.1 / .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, slsvcutil

I use the Silverlight 5 SDK tool *SLSVCUTIL* to generate the WCF service metadata for use with Xamarin.  It's a basic usage passing the URL to the svc and a /d output folder for the generated content.  It's been working great for years.

Today I installed .NET 4.6.1, rebooted, then install VS 2015.1 and it appears something has broken the SLSVCUTIL.  I ran the code in an admin command prompt and the following error appears:

> Error: An error occurred in the tool.
>
> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone know how to resolve this after the latest updates to .NET and Visual Studio 2015?  I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Silverlight 5 SDK but no change.

Comment: This appears to be related to Visual Studio 2015.1 and my guess is something along the lines of the Windows Phone Dev elements.  I tested the SLSVCUTIL on a server that has .NET 4.6.1 and no Visual Studio and it works fine there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran in to this issue today, having also recently updated VS 2015.1.  It seems to have been fixed by applying the following update for Silverlight: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3126036